# Spoiler mechanism not working

Tags: bug, markdown, spoilers

In [a recent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438299/8133) I've tried to hide some text. Unfortunately, something seems broken.

Here's the not-so-hidden text:

> ! Let $X$ be the set of complete theories that satisfy "everything
> is countable" and have unboundedly many $\alpha<\omega_1^L$
> with $L_\alpha$ realising them. The theory of $L_{\omega_1^L}$ is one such theory, and we will be done if we prove that there are some others. Now $X$ is a definable class in $L_{\omega_1^L}$, and so it must have some other elements or else $L_{\omega_1^L}$ would admit a truth defintion ($\varphi$ is true in $L_{\omega_1^L}$ iff the unique element of $X$ contains $\varphi$).

I'm not sure what the bug is. The plain-text version of the passage *also* doesn't hide properly:

> ! let X be the set of complete theories that satisfy "everything
> is countable" and have unboundedly many \alpha<\omega_1^L
> realising them. the theory of L_{\omega_1^L} is one such theory,
> and we will be done if we prove that there are some others. but X is a definable class in L_{\omega_1^L}, and so it must have some other elements, or L_{\omega_1^L} would admit a truth defintion (\phi iff the unique theory in X satisfies \phi).

But spoilering latex seems to work fine:

> This is some latex! $X$ $L_{\omega_1^L}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the source code<sup>1</sup> - this part has a newline after each word:

> ! Spoiler
> with
> multiple
> lines -
> this
> does
> not
> work.

But this happens if I put the same text into a single line:

> Spoiler without  multiple  lines - this seems to work.

Related posts on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [How to do multi-line spoilers properly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285026)
- [Spoiler quotes break when multiple lines get involved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243008)

I will explicitly add that I have only tested this on desktop - not on any mobile device.

<sup>1</sup>You can access the source, for example, from [the revision history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/5570/revisions).

Comment: Oh that's annoying. Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, how did you fix it? (I'm curious how to handle "invisible line breaks.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have [edited your answer](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/438299/revisions) - for me the spoiler now works as expected. (But it's up to you to say whether this is what you wanted.) I hope that somebody who knows more above this will give you a more detailed response - but I wanted to try at least some quick fix.

Comment: Yup, that's great, although I don't actually understand what you changed.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If you wish to, we can [continue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62752692#62752692) - so that we do not leave many comments here. But I didn't really do anything beyond removing a newline.